# Convert User Input Character to Symbol: x86_64 Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am trying to convert an input character to an output symbol in x86 assembly. As an example, if the user enters `A` I want the below to be output:

```
  $  
 $ $
$$$$$
$   $
$   $
```

And for `B`:

```
$$$$
$   $
$$$$
$   $
$$$$
```

etc. My current method is to set up a string of 0's and 1's and then loop through and convert a `0` to a space and a `1` to a `$`. I use a `b` as a line break (i.e. new line) and an `x` as end of string.

My code below (just showing `A` run through to shorten code):

```
section .data
    ; constants
    NULL        equ 0
    EXIT_SUCCESS    equ 0
    EXIT_FAIL   equ 1
    SYS_exit    equ 60
    SYS_read    equ 0
    SYS_write   equ 1
    STD_in      equ 0
    STD_out     equ 1

    ; other
    text1   db "Please enter an upper-case letter from A-E: ",0
    errmsg  db "Error: incorrect letter chosen.",0
    sucmsg  db "Success.",0
    symA    db "00100b01010b11111b10001b10001x ",0
    space   db " "
    dollar  db "$"
    lbreak  db "b"
    lend    db "x"

section .bss
    ; reserve space for user input
    letter resb 1

section .text
    global _start

_start: 
    ; print question
    mov rax, text1
    call _printText

    ; get user input
    ; sys_read (0, latter, 1)
    mov rax, SYS_read
    mov rdi, STD_in
    mov rsi, letter
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall

    ; dereference rsi
    movzx rsi, byte [letter]

    ; jump conditionals
    mov rdx, "A"
    cmp rsi, rdx
    je _printA

    ; default jump if no match
    ; print fail msg
    mov rax, errmsg
    call _printText
    jmp _exitFail

_printA:
    xor eax, eax
    ; sys_write (1, text, 1)
    mov rax, symA
    call _printText
    call _printChar
    jmp _exitSuccess

_exitFail:
    ; default error exit
    ; sys_exit (1)
    mov rax, SYS_exit
    mov rdi, EXIT_FAIL
    syscall

_exitSuccess:
    ; print success msg
    mov rax, sucmsg
    call _printText

    ; sys_exit (0)
    mov rax, SYS_exit
    mov rdi, EXIT_SUCCESS
    syscall

; functions
_printText:
    push rax
    mov rbx, 0

_ptLoop:
    inc rax
    inc rbx
    mov cl, [rax]
    cmp cl, 0
    jne _ptLoop

    mov rax, SYS_write
    mov rdi, STD_out
    pop rsi
    mov rdx, rbx
    syscall
    ret

_printChar:
    ;push rax
    mov rbx, 0
    
_pcLoop:
    inc rax
    inc rbx
    mov cl, [rax]
    ; if 0
    cmp cl, 0
    je _movSpace
    ; if 1
    cmp cl, 1
    je _movSymbol
    ; if newline
    cmp cl, lbreak
    je _movNewLine
    ; if end
    cmp cl, lend
    je _endPrint

_movSpace:
    mov rcx, space
    loop _pcLoop

_movSymbol:
    mov rcx, dollar
    loop _pcLoop    

_movNewLine:
    mov rcx, "\n"
    loop _pcLoop

_endPrint:
    mov rax, SYS_write
    mov rdi, STD_out
    mov rsi, rcx
    mov rdx, rbx
    syscall
    ret
```

Currently, I have tried to debug as I was getting `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` in the `_printChar` function, however, now with the above code I am unable to create the executable file as it is returning the below error:

```
(.text+0x10e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_8 against '.data'
(.text+0x113): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_8 against '.data'
```

when trying to run the below command in terminal:

```
ld filename.o -o filename
```

Can anyone suggest anything to assist with code above to achieve the objective I am after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you make your program with

```
nasm -f elf64 filename.asm -o filename.o -l filename.lst
ld filename.o -o filename
```

Linker reports a problem at `.text+0xca`, so you need to find in the "filename.lst"  what instruction was generated at this offset `0xca` in the `.text` section:

```
    ....
   112 000000C3 80F901                      cmp cl, 1
   113 000000C6 7416                        je _movSymbol
   114                                      ; if newline
   115 000000C8 80F9[78]                    cmp cl, lbreak
   116 000000CB 741D                        je _movNewLine
   117                                      ; if end
   118 000000CD 80F9[79]                    cmp cl, lend
   119 000000D0 741F                        je _endPrint
    ....
```

It's the `cmp cl, lbreak`. Looking at the definition `lbreak db "b"` it obvious that your instruction incorrectly tried to compare a byte-value in `cl` with the **offset** of variable `lbreak` in section `.data`, which happens to be **78**. You probably intended to compare `cl` with the **value** `"b"` stored in memory, using `cmp cl, [lbreak]` or even better, with the **immediate** value: `cmp cl,"b"`.

Also consider printing the big letter as one 0-terminated string, using a single `_printText`:

```
  SECTION .data
  BigA  DB "  $  ",10
        DB " $ $ ",10
        DB "$$$$$",10
        DB "$   $",10
        DB "$   $",10
        DB 0
  BigB  DB "$$$$ ",10
        DB "$   $",10
        DB "$$$$ ",10
        DB "$   $",10
        DB "$$$$ ",10
        DB 0
```